# UINavigationBar displays incorrectly when combine with UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to create Home Screen for UITabBarViewController with another UINavigationViewController and UIViewController Subclass.

In application,There are:

- two Tab for loading NewsController and VideoController
- HomeViewController that loads immediately when application finish launch.

This is my application shot screen.

HomeViewController
[image]

NavigationBar show a half

NewsViewController
[image]

This is my code.

//In TabBarWithHomeDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc]init];

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];

    nav.navigationItem.title = @"Tab 1 Data";
    [nav pushViewController:homeViewController animated:NO]; 


    [self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:nav];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

//In NewsViewController.m for touching on home button

```
-(IBAction) homeButtonClick:(id)sender
{
        TabBarWithHomeAppDelegate * appDelegate 
        = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        UITabBarController * tabBarController =  appDelegate.tabBarController;
        [tabBarController setSelectedViewController:nil];
        [tabBarController setSelectedViewController:appDelegate.homeViewController];

}
```

In addition, I have attached source code. I'm will be grad if you see that and help me to solve this. In fact, I try to do it myself almost 6 hours.

[link to download source code.](http://codesanook.com/code/TabBarWithHome.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HomeViewController is not assigned as a tab in your UITabBarController, so you should not call:

```
[tabBarController setSelectedViewController:appDelegate.homeViewController];
```

You should either make it a real tab or do something different. I would recommend calling

```
[tabBarController presentModalViewController:homeViewController animated:YES];
```

You will not be able to see the tab bar in this scenario so you will need a different way to dismiss the homeViewController. However, this is more correct as it doesn't really make sense for the user to see a tab bar controller with no tabs currently selected.

Comment: Hi Sebastian Celis,
Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, set presentModalViewController as your suggestion, HomeViewController doesn't show on top of screen. :)

Comment: It should. Make sure you are calling it correctly and read the presentModalViewController docs.

Comment: It works now, Thank you very much but how can I control the size of view in HomeViewController defined in nib. When it load to modal of tabBarController, it always fill to full screen size. I want tabbar display on the bottom of screen.

Answer (score 0):

I just comment you code in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` and all works perfect:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi Nekto,
Thank you very much. However, I want the content of HomeviewController show on screen. It show when application launch and touch home button.

Comment: Yes, I do. :) I'think I'm not make this clear. 
I need HomeViewController displaying over UITabBarContrller.
After launching application it show home screen with two tab that load other view controller.